# Node project stuck at `starting node.js` won't connect to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nodemon

I am following a tutorial for the MERN stack and I have this code so far.

```
const app = express();
//setting up to send out requests
app.use(bodyparser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }))
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }))
app.use(cors());

//credentials to database, this is just a test database so don't worry
const CONNECTIONURL = 'mongodb+srv://steve:1@test.lyt6y.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const PORT = process.env.PORT|| 5000;
// connecting to database 
mongoose.connect(CONNECTIONURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server is at port: ${PORT}`)))
    .catch(() => () => console.log(error.message));


mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

When I run `npm start` which starts nodemon for this file, I get the following in the console.

```
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

I am expecting to see what port the server has started on, or at least an error message but I am not seeing either. I'm not sure what's wrong, and there aren't any errors to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Online Git repos are best not linking to unless they are permanent. Use a code runner online or, even better, just ensure your question is self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
const app = express();
//setting up to send out requests
app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }))
app.use(cors());

//credentials to database, this is just a test database so don't worry
const CONNECTIONURL = 'mongodb+srv://steve:1@test.lyt6y.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const PORT = process.env.PORT|| 5000;
// connecting to database 
mongoose.connect(CONNECTIONURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('DB started'))
    .catch(() => () => console.log(error.message));


mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server is at port: ${PORT}`))
```

Comment: this is working, what exactly did you change?

Comment: Your database is probably not connecting since it doesn't log DB started when I try with your link, but it worked for me with localhost

Comment: even your original code works if you write a valid mongodb url

Comment: I'm at a point where the node project works, but I never get the console log that says ```Db started``` which means that it isn't connecting, but i also never get the error message. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Can you check your DB link? I think the domain mongodb.net doesn't exist

Comment: i got the link from mondgo.db's code example.

Comment: try `mongodb://localhost:27017/example` if you have mongodb installed locally